# How to uninstall nonexistent HID devices that persist accross windows installs

Tags: windows, drivers, hid

[image]

When I reinstalled windows, my trackpad was not working. as part of one of the trouble shooting steps, I added some human interface devices manually, which are non-existent.
(step was to manually add a HID compliant touchpad driver).

Now, I have reinstalled windows 3 times, and even completely formatted the SSD in which windows is installed yet, windows automatically add those drivers in every install. I can't uninstall also, as it gets automatically added. what to do to permanently remove them?

I am sure that it is not a required HID device, as there was no such device before. and i can still add those fake devices, just can't remove.

any help would be appreciated...

Comment: If it was truly nonexistent, Windows would not install it. Use Device Manager’s “by connection” view to find out to which physical device they belong. There’s a trick: Select the device you want to inspect, then while it is still selected, switch the view. The new tree will be expanded to the same device.

Comment: Try the [Device Cleanup Tool](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html) whose usage is described [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/device-cleanup-tool-windows).

Comment: I tried the device cleanup, and it did not work. it just pops back after i refresh.

Comment: It is not useful, as I myself added it. and i can still add more, just not remove it.